# Proper way to move user directory to a new home partition

Tags: users, home

If I have an existing user `user` with an existing home directory `/home/user`, what is the proper way to move his home directory a new home partition?

Simply copying the directory with `cp` does not preserve owner and timestamps (unless I use the appropriate `cp` options). Would `cp` be enough? And what options should be used to make sure everything is copied correctly?

Comment: I'd use `rsync -avH /home/user/ /mnt/newhome/user/`.

Comment: `cp -a` should get this done. But this will not preserve the file system attributes (`man lsattr`); so won't `rsync`, though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797819/command-to-change-the-default-home-directory-of-a-user

Answer (score 1):

I use `cp -vfa`, but the `rsync -vaH` (mentioned by @Kusalananda in a comment) would also work. In the case of latter, don't forget that *all* directories should end with `/` (i.e. `/home/gradient` will be not okay, `/home/gradient/` yes).

Once in a life we all should really read the `ls`, `cp`, `rm`, `bash` and `rsync` manual pages, they can really *a lot*.

---

If the target directory is on the same partition, a simple `mv -vf` would be also ok.

Don't forget to update the home directory entry belonging to the user in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Don't forget `pax -r -w -l`.

Answer (score 0):

These days the `mv` command will copy across partitions and delete the original.
I'm not sure how it will cope if interrupted and restarted, which may be an issue for large home directories.